# What is the problem with this code in Python? I don't understand its error

Tags: python

```
import sys

seconds = int(sys.argv[7464643])
s = seconds % 60
m = seconds // 60 % 60
h = seconds // 60 // 60 % 24
d = seconds // 60 // 60 // 24 % 365
y = seconds // 60 // 60 // 24 // 365

print(seconds,"Sekunden sind",y,"Jahr(e),",d,"Tag(e),",h,"Stunde(n),",m,"Minute(n) 
und",s,"Sekunde(n).")
```

What is the problem with this code? I don't understand the error

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Please edit your post and add it.

Comment: What are you expecting `sys.argv[7464643]` to do? Have your [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)?

Comment: Try `print(sys.argv)` ... it likely has fewer values than 7464643.

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion by looking at his code you can easily tell that he is getting `IndexError`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Here is the problem I want to solve: Write a program that contains an integer as the program parameter. This should be saved in a variable seconds. Enter the number of years, days, hours, minutes and seconds. You can assume that there are 365 days each year. The output should be structured as follows:

Comment: @DeBos Not necessarily, he might be passing 7,464,643 command line arguments. No way to know for sure.

Comment: @tdelaney yes this is 1

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion did you see someone passing that much arguments? I didn't. By looking at his code you can easily guess what he is trying to do.

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fc900d5f1110> in <module>
      1 import sys
      2 
----> 3 seconds = int (sys.argv[1])
      4 s = seconds % 60
      5 m = seconds // 60 % 60

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-f'

Comment: @DeBos- or OP made a mistake when posting the code. This question needs to clearly state the error and it should include a traceback. Otherwise its just down the rabbit hole.

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion What OS would support 7,464,643 command line arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace `sys.argv[7464643]` with `sys.argv[1]` to get first argument from the command line.

Comment: I did it, but I still get this error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fc900d5f1110> in <module>
      1 import sys
      2 
----> 3 seconds = int (sys.argv[1])
      4 s = seconds % 60
      5 m = seconds // 60 % 60

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-f'

Comment: How are you running your code? If you are running it like this: `python main.py number_of_seconds` then you shouldn't get this error anymore. If it's not what you are doing, give more examples of what you are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: I am not experienced in programming. It's a student project and here is the problem I only copied that in Jupiter notebook.
Write a program that contains an integer as the program parameter. This should be saved in a variable seconds. Enter the number of years, days, hours, minutes and seconds. You can assume that there are 365 days each year. The output should be structured as follows:

Comment: So it should work then. `sys.argv[1]` will be first program parameter e.g. if you will run your program like that: `python main.py 10` then `sys.argv[1]` will be equal to `10`

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is an array containing all of your command line arguments. Index 0 will be the name of your program, index 1 will be your first argument, etc. What you want to do is change your second line to read `seconds = int(sys.argv[1])`, then run your program from the command line with `python filename.py 7464643` where filename.py is replaced with the name of your file.